# Webaudio Recorder how to record output

Tags: stream, streaming, media, web-audio-api, mediarecorder

I have this code to record an audio source :

```
recordingstream=contextAudio.createMediaStreamDestination();
recorder=new MediaRecorder(recordingstream.stream);
source.connect(recordingstream);
                
source.start(0,ndeb,nfin);
recorder.start();
```

width :

```
source.onended = () => {
     sourcEtat=0;
    recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable',function(e){
                             
   document.getElementById("renduWav").src=URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
                             
  document.getElementById("renderAudio").style.display="block";
        recorder=false;
        recordingstream=false;
  });
  recorder.stop();
};
```

This code record the buffer of the source but not the transformed source. How to record the output of source.start(…) ?

This code record the buffer of the source but not the transformed source. How to record the output of source.start(…) ?